# stripe create payment intent with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, payment

I am trying to make a payment with stripe.I make the payment  and could see the success response on the browser but when I check in the dashboard it isn't adding there.

```
const express = require("express");
const stripe = require("stripe")("enter your API sk_test");

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.post("/charge", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
      {
        amount: 200,
        currency: "gbp",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        receipt_email: "hadeklte@gmail.com",
      },
      function (err, paymentIntent) {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error("failed to charge");
        }
        res.status(200).send(paymentIntent);
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, "error occure");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up at ${port}`);
});
```

response of the above some thing like this

```
{
    "id": "pi_1HF19PGz03sGbVedIHyeBeLq",
    "object": "payment_intent",
    "amount": 200,
    "amount_capturable": 0,
    "amount_received": 0,
    "application": null,
    "application_fee_amount": null,
    "canceled_at": null,
    "cancellation_reason": null,
    "capture_method": "automatic",
    "charges": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1HF19PGz03sGbVedIHyeBeLq"
    },
    ...
}
```

after checking the docs I saw, to continue I should attach payment method and confirm the payment [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create).Then to confirm I use this line of code

```
app.post("/charge", async (req, res, next) => {
  let charged;
  try {
    await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
      {
        amount: 200,
        currency: "gbp",
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        receipt_email: "hadeklte@gmail.com",
      },
      function (err, paymentIntent) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, "failed payment");
        }
        charged = paymentIntent.id;
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }

  console.log(charged);
  try {
    await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
   // "pi_1HF19PGz03sGbVedIHyeBeLq",
        charged
      { payment_method: "pm_card_visa" },
      function (err, paymentIntent) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, "failed confirmation");
        }
        res.status(200).send(paymentIntent);
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

and it respond an success if I pass the paramater to stripe.paymentIntent.confirm as string, like the one I commented it does work but when I pass the Id as a charged It does throw me an error

```
undefined
Error: Stripe: Argument "intent" must be a string, but got: undefined (on API request to `POST /payment_intents/{intent}/confirm`)
    at urlParams.reduce (E:\projects\Stripe\Stripe_API_Docs\node_modules\stripe\lib\makeRequest.js:21:13)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at getRequestOpts (E:\projects\Stripe\Stripe_API_Docs\node_modules\stripe\lib\makeRequest.js:18:29)
    at Promise (E:\projects\Stripe\Stripe_API_Docs\node_modules\stripe\lib\makeRequest.js:69:14)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at makeRequest (E:\projects\Stripe\Stripe_API_Docs\node_modules\stripe\lib\makeRequest.js:66:10)
    at Constructor.confirm (E:\projects\Stripe\Stripe_API_Docs\node_modules\stripe\lib\StripeMethod.js:31:7)
    at app.post (E:\projects\Stripe\Stripe_API_Docs\app.js:70:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5) 'failed confirmation'
```

now how could I pass the paymentIntent.id created in the create function to the confirm function with out undefined.

Comment: You want to run that second function `stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(` inside of the callback function `function (err, paymentIntent) {` you are running into a scope issue that is why it is undefined

Comment: For future reference, never ever ever ever post your `client_secret` anywhere, from now till the end of ever. Since you did, you'll have to revoke that secret and get a generate a new one.

Comment: Hi Ermias, to make this simpler, rather than having two separate calls; one to create the payment intent and another right after to confirm the payment intent. You can create and confirm the payment intent in one call as shown in this example here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously#web-create-payment-intent. Basically you provide the `payment_method` when creating the payment intent and also specify a `confirm` parameter set to `true`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirm

Answer (score 1):

For typescript

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

...

const paymentIntent: Stripe.PaymentIntent = await 
stripeClient.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: amount * 100, 
        currency: 'usd'
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

finally I figured out The problem was scope as @JimithyPicker
stated

```
app.post("/charge", async (req, res, next) => {
  var charged;
  try {
    charged = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 200,
      currency: "gbp",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      receipt_email: "hadeklte@gmail.com",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }

  console.log(charged);
  try {
    const paymentConfirm = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
      charged.id,
      { payment_method: "pm_card_visa" }
    );
    res.status(200).send(paymentConfirm);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }

});
```