# TypeError: stripe.terminal.readers.processPaymentIntent is not a function

Tags: node.js, terminal, stripe-payments

i am using stripe terminal reader for payment collection (using Node js), when i do second step of collect payment i.e., process the payment...it is giving me error "TypeError: stripe.terminal.readers.processPaymentIntent is not a function".

document link : https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/collect-payment?terminal-sdk-platform=server-driven#process-payment

below is my code:

```js
 process_stripe_payment(req, callback){
        stripe.terminal.readers.processPaymentIntent( 
            'reader_id',
            {payment_intent: 'payment_intent'}
        ),function(err, res){
            console.log(err);
            if(res){
                console.log('success');
            }else{
                console.log('failed');
            }
        };
  },
```

Comment: You need to post where `stripe` comes from.

Comment: @StevenSpungin it is code of stripe.js and i have defined it in starting of js file like const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY); –

Comment: The stripe docs call an async function (loadStripe) to initialize. Did you do that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998980/import-stripe-using-node-js-typescript

Comment: @StevenSpungin I have checked above link and tried but didnt work for me. it is still giving error

Comment: The next step I would suggest is to log your stripe object to the console, or set a breakpoint and inspect it.

Comment: Also, try this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363993/stripe-create-payment-intent-with-nodejs